# addJSONData jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to use `addJSONData` function for adding a new row to my jqGrid.

```
$("#grid_id")[0].addJSONData(newRowJSONData);
```

It works, but when I try

```
$("#grid_id")[1].addJSONData(newRowJSONData)
```

this gives an undefined error please help me how can I add more than one new row to jqGrid?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `$("#grid_id")[1]` means the *second* element on the page, which has the id equal to `grid_id`. Because the ids **must be unique** on the page the expression `$("#grid_id")[1]` produce `undefined` result. So `$("#grid_id")[1].addJSONData(newRowJSONData)` should gives an error.

I don't understand you statement: "I want to use `addJSONData` function for adding a new row to my jqGrid.". I could understand that you what to fill the grid with data which you have as an object, but I see no sense in the requirement to use an special method. If you need some help you should describe your real problem without the choosing of one special method. Then other people could try to help you.